# Why is Ruby not part of RHEL/CentOS?

Tags: ruby, linux, centos, rhel

It seems that Red Hat doesn't include software that is made by a company. OpenVPN and MongoDB come to mind. Perl and Python are in RHEL/CentOS. What could be a reason Ruby isn't in RHEL?

**Update**

RedHat have now [announced](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/06/05/red-hat-software-collections-1-0-beta-now-available/) Red Hat Software Collections 1.0 which exactly addresses this need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use distribution rubies. It is best to compile them from the latest version or whatever version you use, those packages in the distro repositories are frequently outdated.

Check out RVM or RBENV.  I guess why they are not could be interesting, but probably not a question StackOverflow at large is going to like.